# how to solve this below runtime error 430?

Tags: sql-server, vba, vb6

I created one application (*.exe) it works fine in all systems but in one system it throws an error.

> "class does not support automation or does support expected interface "

[image]

Comment: which windows you are using?

Comment: If you were to take the time to press the `Debug` button, it would highlight the code that is failing. That would point you at the COM object that is causing the issue. Please do some googling before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple [Google search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/class-does-not-support-automation-or-does-not-support-expected-interface):

Either the class you specified in the `GetObjec`t or `CreateObject` function call has not exposed a programmability interface, or you changed a project from .dll to .exe, or vice versa.

To correct this error Check the documentation of the application that created the object for limitations on the use of automation with this class of object.

If you changed a project from .dll to .exe or vice versa, you must manually unregister the old .dll or .exe.

Comment: it works in all systems but problem in one system

Answer (score 0):

It will Occurs when launching an installation of FRx that resides in a different directory than the one that was specified when FRx was installed on the current workstation. For example, launching an FRx install that resides on the server, instead of the one that was installed locally. Register the FRXLICSYS.DLL and FRXSYSTEM.DLL files in the directory from which FRx is being launched. If the problem persists, uninstall and reinstall FRx Version 6.0

Note If you are running Microsoft FRx version 6.7, register the FRXLICSYS67.DLL file, instead of the FRXLICSYS.DLL file.

follow below steps to resolve your concern:
Manually register the required files.

1. Using Explorer, locate FRXLICSYS.DLLin the directory from which FRx is being run.

Note If you are running Microsoft FRx version 6.7, locate the FRXLICSYS67.DLL file, instead of the FRXLICSYS.DLL file.

2. Choose Open With from the menu.
3. Click the Other button at the bottom of the Open With window.
4. Browse to the local drive (most often C:), and select either REGSVR32.EXE in \WINNT\SYSTEM32 or REGSVR.EXE in \WINDOWS\SYSTEM.
5. Click Open.
6. Click OK. A message will display indicating whether the file was successfully registered.
7. Repeat steps 1 through6 for FRXSYSTEM.DLL.

Comment: This doesn't just happen for FRx... it's any COM library.